# How to Empty-Initialize a `const` Member

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, initialization, constants

**I have a situation where I have a `const` member variable, but in some control paths I can guarantee that I won't access it.  In these cases, when I construct the object, I don't want to waste time initializing that member.**

---

Consider the following toy example:

```
struct Foo {
    int val;
    Foo() {}
};
auto function() { return Foo(); }
```

This produces the desired assembly (Clang 5.0.0 `-O3`):

```
function():                           # @function()
        ret
```

However, if I change `int val;` into `int const val;`, as I desire, the compilation fails (because `const` members must be initialized):

```
struct Foo {
    int const val;
    Foo() {} //<- Fails!  `const` members must be initialized.
};
```

**How can I initialize `int const val;`, but without imposing any runtime cost?  E.g., how should I fix the marked line in the example above?**

---

Note: default-initializing `val` (i.e., using `Foo() : val() {}` or `Foo() = default;`) is *not acceptable*, since this zero-initializes `val`:

```
function():                           # @function()
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

Comment: Are you _really_ in a situation where `xor     eax, eax` is unacceptable? If so, what exactly is that situation?

Comment: In the case of a measly, lousy `int`, one will need to use the world most accurate atomic clock in order to measure the gain (if there is any) from not initializing the aforementioned `int`. Just zero-initialize it, then move on to more pressing matters. In cases of more expensive objects, `std::optional` will be the likely solution.

Comment: @NeilButterworth As I wrote, this is a toy example. IRL, `val` might be an actual object, in which case the overhead can be arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 0):

You should first ask the question of whether this is possible, and if yes how.

In this case the answer is *no*, since a const data member of a class has to be initialized, either by you, or by the default initializing value.

---

PS: This has to be a classic case of premature optimization, since initializing variables is relateively cheap in terms of time.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just an int, you can't really save time.
If it's way more complex, use `std::optional<T>`. It's extremely cheap to initialize it (a single bit is set to 0 if empty), you can query if it was initialized, it's only one bit of overhead in memory and like zero in runtime (dereference if known to be non-empty has no `if` in sensible optimized implementations).

```
extern bool ShouldInit;

struct Foo {
    std::optional<MyExpensiveType> oMyStuff_;
    Foo()
        : oMyStuff(ShouldInit ? make_optional<MyExpensiveType>()
                              : std::nullopt) {}
    int fn()
    {
        return oMyStuff_ ? *oMyStuff_
                           : 0;
    }
};
```